# How did "possess" come to have a Z sound for its first double-S?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation

Simple question. How did the English word "possess" come to have a voiced "Z" sound for the first double-S?

Are there any other words that have this? Doesn't double-S consistently mean an unvoiced S sound, across a number of Germanic languages, English included?

Comment: This question's kind of upside down! The writing is just a way to try to capture the sound. The sound is /z/, so the question is how did it come tone spelled with a double < s >?

Comment: @Araucaria Not really in this case. _Possess_ is a loan from French, where it has an unvoiced /s/ (also written ⟨ss⟩), and French /s/ is normally borrowed as /s/, not /z/; cf. _assess_, which is from the same root, only with a different prefix. So the question of how it came to be written with a double ⟨s⟩ is trivial: because that’s how it’s written in French. But the question of how it came to be pronounced with /z/ in English, instead of the /s/ found in every other language where the word appears, is an interesting one.

Comment: The rule in English, such as it is, is that between an unstressed and a stressed vowel, /s/ > /z/. The spellings <ss> and <sc> did not undergo that change in French or Anglo-Latin, but English by default did not care. Possess is actually following the default rule of English, as “poeZES” (Jespersen §6.64). That shows you that English ignored by default the fact that the words were spelled with a <sc> or <ss>: the rule /s/ > /z/ /_ˈV was a rule of English, whatever was going on in French. (From Quora)

Comment: @user66974 Can you provide any other examples of this rule? It is not particularly frequent that a sibilant appears in the position after an unstressed vowel before a stressed vowel without a morpheme boundary before it (_beset_, _aside_, _asunder_; or with Latin boundaries, _assist_, _assess_, _assume_, _decide_, _desist_, _disciple_, etc.), but in most cases I can think of where one does, it’s /s/, not /z/. The only other cases I can think of where it’s /z/ are _disease_ (which has a morpheme boundary _after_ the /s/, _dis-ease_) and _hussar_ (probably from German, so borrowed with /z/).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet -     Scissors: In the case of scissors, the word started out as as sisoures (originally from Latin cisoria); it was respelled as scissors to look like the completely unrelated Latin word scissor “tailor”.

Comment: That means that it was originally pronounced as “siZOORZ”, with the accent in the end, like for any French word borrowed into English. As with other such French words (prison, reason, season), the “z” pronunciation stuck after we shifted the stress to the initial syllable, making them match Germanic (Jespersen §6.67). But during that whole process, the double <ss> (which does prevent “z” within French) was cosmetic.

Comment: @user66974 — If your rule stands consistent, so why _cassette_ is [kəˈ**s**ɛt]  and not [kəˈ**z**ɛt] ?

Comment: See also: https://www.jstor.org/stable/30248933

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Alex B’s excellent answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/611270/2587) is correct and authoritative, but a bit heavy on technical language which many readers may not be familiar with.  I’ll try to give a self-contained answer in slightly plainer language, summarising that answer together with some context from comments on the question, and answering OP’s specific questions directly — but this draws heavily on Alex B’s answer, and the sources linked there.

***Possess* is spelled with *ss* because it’s a loanword from French**; in French it was spelled with *ss* to represent the unvoiced sound /s/, and the borrowed English spelling was modelled on the French.  **After borrowing to English, the /s/ changed pronunciation to /z/ because it’s between two vowels and following an unstressed syllable.** This pronunciation change occurred fairly systematically in English around the 16th century, and so **there are various other words like this, e.g. *dessert*, *dissolve*, *example*, *Alexander*.**  On the other hand, words borrowed later missed this change, so e.g. *cassette* is still pronounced with /s/ rather than /z/.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct, I think some of the technical language meant I missed the answers to my questions, especially about the difference between earlier loanwords and later ones.

Comment: Hrmpf, not only are i. "because it’s a loanword from French" and ii. "because it’s between two vowels and following an unstressed syllable" not very technical by any common standard. The focus on voicing as such is far too reductive to account for anything. The voicing attributed to Verner's law in AlexB.'s answer was conditioned by stress, which fixed differently in English. This is ignoring Medieval Latin, which was the written "standard" rather than French, and that's a bottomless pit to be honest. It's pretty easy to say you are wrong here because you are not correct at all.

Comment: @vectory "It's pretty easy to say you are wrong here because you are not correct at all." What is the point of this sentence?

Comment: Modern French «exemple» and «Alexandre» are pronounced with /gz/ instead of /ks/. Were they /ks/ before? (If it's relevant, from what I can tell as a learner, the rule is: A single consonant letter between vowels means it's voiced and a double means unvoiced, including things where English differs, like «absoudre» /aps-/ vs "absolve" /əbz-/.)

Comment: Erm I don't get your last two examples. The /z/ in *Alexander* is not between two vowels and the same goes for *example*!!!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.: Absolutely, in those examples its not exactly the same change of just /s/ getting voiced to /z/ — it’s the combined sequence /ks/ getting voiced to /gz/, which seems to have occurred as part of the same systematic change (according to the Minkova 2014 book as cited in Alex B.’s answer).

Comment: @Alex You're right! I'm not sure why I thought that. But «exact» is another example.

Comment: @wjandrea I just added some new info - let me know if you have further questions

Answer (score 28):

Here's a quote from [Upward and Davidson 2011](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9781444342994):

> "Voicing of intervocalic /s/ to /z/, written *s* or *ss*, after an unstressed syllable in words such as *desist*, *resist* (compare the pronunciation of *consist*, *insist*), *dessert*, *possess* occurred in EModE, at first with both voiced and voiceless forms co-existing" (p. 189).

EModE stands for Early Modern English, i.e. c. 1476- c.1660 (Ibid, p. xiv), so in the much later French borrowings it was **not** operational e.g. in *cassette* (its first attested use in the OED goes back only to 1793 meaning 'casket').

Cf. Minkova 2014 ([the online companion](https://edinburghuniversitypress.com/media/resources/Historical_Phonology_of_English_-_Online_Companion.pdf) to her 2014 textbook, [A historical phonology of English](https://edinburghuniversitypress.com/book-a-historical-phonology-of-english.html)):

“Lack of stress and possibly ambisyllabic status will account for the voicing of [s] in the early Modern English voicing in French and Latin loans such as *po**ss**ess*, *de**ss**ert*, *di**ss**olve*, where the conditions of voicing replicate Verner’s Law (see 3.4.1). The prefix *dis*- was commonly voiced prevocalically in the eighteenth century – *disarm*, *dishonour*, *disorder* – but only *disaster* and *disease* maintain the voicing” (p. 24).

In the above-mentioned 2014 textbook she describes this change as

> “a sixteenth-century tendency to voice fricatives after unstressed syllables, manifested in the voicing of /s/ to /z/ in loanwords, mostly, but not exclusively after prefixes – *re**s**ig*n, *tran**s**act*, *e**x**ample*, *Ale**x**ander* – and even against the spelling in *po**ss**ess*, *de**ss**ert*, *di**ss**olve*” (p. 66).

**A note re: pronunciation of French example, exact etc.:**

Obviously, the English words *example* and *exact* were borrowed a while ago, the first attested uses listed in the OED are

- *exacte* (1533, T. More “Suche exacte cyrcumspeccion”) – borrowed from Latin, cf. the first attested use of *exact, -e* in French is ca. 1542 (Dictionnaire historique de la langue francaise);
- *exsaumple* (ca1382, “Bi this exsaumple [Latin hoc exemplo]” – borrowed from French. In Middle English there was a lot of variation, so we can also find such forms as e*xsample, exsaumpyll, exsaunpyll, exsawmple, exsaumple* – which means those were pronounced with [ks].

It’s important to note that Latin *ex-* changed in Old French to either *ss* (before a vowel) or *s* (before a consonant), see [Zink 2013:](https://www.puf.com/content/Phon%C3%A9tique_historique_du_fran%C3%A7ais) 233. So we have

Latin *exagium* > French *essai*

Latin *extendere* > French *étendre* (cf. Old French *estendre*)

Whenever you see a French word beginning with *ex-*, it means it was either much later borrowed from Latin (like *exact, -e* ca. 1542) or its spelling was changed during the so called Erasmian reform (like *exemple*).

Latin *exemplum* > Old French *es(s)ample, essemple*

*Note*: [Kibler 1984](https://www.mla.org/Publications/Bookstore/Introductions-to-Older-Languages/An-Introduction-to-Old-French) “x in Latin represented the combination /k+s/; it may represent the same sound in Old French” (except in the word-final position where it stood for -us, p. 19)

Pierre Fouché in the third volume of his *Phonétique historique du français* ([v. III Les consonnes et index général](https://archive.org/details/phonetiquehistor0003fouc/mode/2up)) mentions that in the sixteenth century, we encounter such forms in French as *ezemple, euzemple, ezerice, euzecuter* – which means those were pronounced with [z] (not [gz]!) in Middle French and up until the sixteenth century. Then during the Erasmian reform the kind of pronunciation closer to Latin was "restored" in such French words, cf.

« Il est vrai qu'à côté de *egzemple*, on a prononcé aussi *eksemple*. Cette prononciation était encore en usage du temps de [Vaugelas (1647)](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k84316s/f374.item) qui la condamne d'ailleurs. Elle correspond à une prononciation plus savante du latin (=*eksemplum*), celle qui a été indiquée plus haut résultant d'un compromis avec la prononciation ancienne soit du français, soit du latin lui-même » (p. 874).

Comment: Upward & Davidson's implied pronunciation of *desist* as *dezist* is curious. Who says that?

Comment: @JohnBentin well, I have to admit, as I was typing it, I myself had to look it up in the dictionaries because I found it odd - but, all the major English dictionaries published in the last twenty years do list both variants, with [s] (usually the primary variant) and [z]. That being said, the latest Fowler (2015, ed. by Jeremy Butterfield) literally says the following, **"Traditionally pronounced as [dɪˈzɪst], but [dɪˈsɪst] is an acceptable variant."**

Comment: I (AmE native speaker) have never heard anyone, in any media, pronounce “desist” with any [z] sound anywhere. I wonder how much the fixed pair “cease and desist” has played a role in that...

Comment: I definitely say *desist* with a /z/. Brit.

Answer (score -6):

There are two questions.

> Doesn't double-S consistently mean an unvoiced S sound, across a number of Germanic languages, English included?

That's irrelevant since the spelling does originate from a common Germanic parent. The spelling does not dictate the pronunciation, except in spelling pronounciation. Nor is there an obvious morphologic rule from Latin to apply.

> Simple question. How did the English word "possess" come to have a voiced "Z" sound for the first double-S?

It doesn't? I mean, I didn't know it does.

The etymology that makes it cognate to *potesse*, *potential* is also no help since t is voiceless to begin with. Unless it should formally have been **testo* with a ***-d-* coda prefix, such as *address* vs. *assent* vs. *ad-tention*, it would have to be an English thing as determjned by @AlexB. However ...

Since the image of *emperor stomping fallen guy* is exceedingly common in ancient art (see eg. the Namor Stele), implying taking of PoW, I have no trouble believing that **ped- "step" (whence *feet*, *pedes*, etc.) is tangentially related, but I am pretty sure there are no authoritative sources to confirm this and I have no idea what to reconstruct in the bell end.

The German standard translation is *besitzen*, specifally *besessen* "possessed" (as of demons), indicating *sed* "sit" (cp. *squat (a building)*?).

> Are there any other words that have this?

In Latin? How about English for a start, *Boss*? *Buzz* instead of *booze*, and consequently *buzzed* to show which is correct, thus the *fuzz* belongs to (voiced?) *fuse* (often spelled *fuze*, a circuit breaker, German *Schütz*, literally *prötection*?).

Geminate *-zz-* exists in many more words which spelling adheres to English pronunciation rather than the typical hypercorrect Lateinasation of *i(s)land* (which, if true and originally voiced, should become *Ireland*, a land of law, origin uncertain).